# A is concerned more with verb than B

Tags: translation

How do I say that a when concerned with noun1, more of a verb is done than concerned with noun2?

For example, more barbequing is done in South African cuisine than British cuisine.
Or; South African cuisine has more barbequing than British cuisine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Perhaps try rewriting your question, and also show your own attempts to create the sort of sentence you want in Japanese.  Otherwise, this will be construed as a translation request, which will most likely get downvotes and closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

> A is concerned more with verb than B
>   For example, more barbequing is done in South African cuisine than British cuisine. Or; South African cuisine has more barbequing than British cuisine.

Whether the structure of AよりBのほうが can be used as the subject of a verb?
Surely, yes.

When taking the cooking method as the subject, it could be something like
より多{おお}くのバーベキューによる調理{ちょうり}**が**南{みなみ}アフリカの料理{りょうり}において**より**イギリス料理においてなされる, but we probably prefer to say something like
バーベキューによる調理**は**イギリス料理**よりも**南アフリカの料理**のほうが多い。**

★ **も is optional.**

When taking the cuisine as the subject, it might be something like
南アフリカの料理**は**イギリス料理**よりも**バーベキューによる調理**が多い。**
Also you can say something like
南アフリカの料理はイギリス料理**に比{くら}べて**バーベキューによる調理が多い。

Comment: Thanks for answering! Although, I think I was getting a bit ahead of myself as these sentences are a bit more complicated than I'm used to.